# Non-Random Particle Emission from all vertices

Tags: particles

Is there a way to control the emission of particles from a mesh vertices so that they are emitted sequentially from each vertex in turn?

If I set the emission to Random then the particles are emitted evenly from each vertex, but the sequence is indeterminate. If I set the emission to non-random then one vertex emits all of its particles first, followed by all of them from the next vertex, followed by all from the next one, and so on.

Is it possible to have the emission for individual particles in sequence. ie, given a cube with 8 vertexes to emit from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, etc.

At the moment I'm just getting 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,......, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,.....3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.... etc.

[image: particle tracks]

Note : The cube started at the origin and travelled along the path shown by the particles (which are not affected by gravity). You can clearly see that they're all emitted from one vertex first, then the next (where there's a break in the line of particles), then the next. I want to be able to emit in strict sequence, one at a time.

Incidentally, I don't actually care *what* sequence they are emitted from, just as long as each set of (8) vertices emit in the same sequence for each set of (8) particles.

---

EDIT: I haven't been able to come up with a way around this and it seems the latest Blender versions don't address it. Possibly 'Everything Nodes' might eventually solve it but that's an unknown time in the future. I've raised it on the developer website as an issue : [Particle Emission from Vertices non-random emission sequence](https://developer.blender.org/T79339). Hopefully a nice Blender developer can work some magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t possible at present. The node system is being radically redesigned with Everything Nodes at which point we should be able to do this and so much more.

Comment: Not completely relevant, in context.. but, a shader get-around, using particle index and transparency?

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts, doesn't help, I'm afraid - can still only set either Random or Non-Random. In non-random the behaviour is to emit from each vertex (or face) in turn as shown above - so you get all particles from one vertex then all from the next, and so on. So there is no way to get particles emitting evenly (and non-randomly) from all vertices (or faces) at once. Only other solution I could come up with was to emit from empties parented to each of the vertices (with each empty having its own particle system) but that was really really cumbersome.